# How to insert <title> in SVG using native JS in IE11?

Tags: javascript, svg, title, internet-explorer-11

I got this:

```
<svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="mydefs.svg#hello"><title>hello world</title></use></svg>
```

I also tried using:

```
// "this" is the svg element already
var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
use.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "mydefs.svg#hello");

var title = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "title");
title.textContent = "hello world";

this.appendChild(use);
this.insertBefore(title, use);
```

However, after it exits the function, IE11 simply replaced the inner content of the svg with the `path` that were defined from `mydefs.svg` ignoring completely the dynamic `title` tag that i tried to put in there.

If i put the `title` directly in the `mydefs.svg`, then i will see the `title` tag, however when you mouse hover, the tooltip will not show up either.

What's the correct way to generate the `title` tag for SVG in IE11?

Comment: What is `t`?  If you want to produce the same result as your sample SVG, shouldn't that line be `use.appendChild(title)`?

Comment: Yeah, is `title`, `t` was supposed to be "hello world" that i tried to set for  `textContent`. Just copy paste error as i create this question.